# Как сделать отображение текста в ячейке Excel без переноса слов?

Tags: excel, fastreport

Есть Excel отчёт, построенный на FastReport.

Пример части кода отчёта, отвечающей за вывод данных

```
 <GroupHeaderBand Name="GroupHeader1" Top="107.95" Width="1247.4" Condition="[testDataSource.testfield1]" SortOrder="None">
  <GroupHeaderBand Name="GroupHeader2" Top="111.95" Width="1247.4" Condition="[testDataSource.testfield2]">
    <GroupHeaderBand Name="GroupHeader3" Top="115.95" Width="1247.4" Condition="[testDataSource.testfield3]">
      <DataBand Name="Data1" Top="119.95" Width="1247.4" Height="18.9" DataSource="testDataSource">
        <TextObject Name="Text9" Width="198.45" Height="18.9" Border.Lines="All" Text="[testDataSource.testfield1]" VertAlign="Top" HorzAlign="Left" WordWrap="false" Trimming="Character"/>

        //...
```

Пример форматирования, которое получаем для поля `testDataSource.testfield1` можно увидеть здесь - ячейка 90:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Полный текст ячейки:

```
Test11 Test22 Test33 Test44 Test55 Test66 Test77 Test88
```

Если зайти в свойства форматирования ячейки сформированного отчёта в Excel-е, то `WrapText` отмечено, т.е. `= true`.

Если его убрать, то получаем результат как в ячейке 91. Именно такой результат и нужен, чтобы в ячейку помещалось максимальное кол-во символов слова и оно просто бы обрезалось.

Как этого можно добиться и правильно ли получается, что word wrap не срабатывает?

Получается, проблема в том, чтобы в excel отчёте у ячейки убрать свойство Wrap Text.

Comment: Уточните, что действительно нужно: обрезание текста или отключение переноса в ячейке. В строке 90 текст не обрезан: если ее расширить, будет видно, что текст переносится ниже. В строке 91 тоже не обрезан - он продолжается в одной строке, но, так как ячейка справа заполнена, текст не отображается (проверить можно, расширив столбец).

Comment: Нужно, чтобы было как в ячейке 91). Т.е. чтобы мы видели максимально возможное кол-во текста в ячейке.

Comment: Как в ячейке - обрезать лишний текст или как в яченйке - без переноса текста? Я не знаю, как работает  *FastReport*, но уточнение для тех, кто сможет помочь. Если нужно не переносить текст и  *FastReport* использует готовый файл (или файл-шаблон), попробуйте в нужном столбце отключить перенос текста в ячейках

Comment: Перенос текста уже отключен (WordWrap="false")